# How to access Window & Document objects in Aurelia?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, aurelia

What is the best way to access `Document` and `Window` objects in `ES6` / `Aurelia` framework? I did try accessing `window` directly in my Aurelia code and it does seem to work, but is that the proper way or is there an Aurelia/ES6 way of doing that?

Specifically, I want to access properties like [window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and [window.sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). I'm just starting with Aurelia and ES6, so I'm a little noob on how to do this one though I would like to follow the standards.

Something like the following:

```
constructor() {
    this.user = JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.user || window.localStorage.user);
}
```

That code actually work in Aurelia, but is that correct to write it this way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is the correct way to do it in Aurelia when working with Web APIs, so you're fine with the code you currently have.

However, when working with the DOM you can of course use the standard DOM API as well, but Aurelia has a Platform Abstraction Layer ([PAL docs](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/api/aurelia/pal)) that will abstract whatever platform your application resides on with a DOM-like API.

For example, the equivalent of `document.getElementById` would be

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework'
import {DOM} from 'aurelia-pal'

@inject(DOM)
export class Home {
  constructor(DOM) {
    this.DOM = DOM
  }

  attached() {
    let element = this.DOM.getElementById('someId')
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, PAL isn't really doing much at the moment but in the future it is planned to allow you to work with your everyday DOM API calls even though your application may not be running in a "normal" DOM.

One very important thing not to forget is that the native DOM & Web APIs are really powerful and there is nothing wrong with using their native implementations. Other frameworks tend to build their own implementation around the Web API's that is tailored to their frameworks' structures and best-practices but that is not necessarily the best thing.

Comment: I had to read your answer twice to understand that I was actually using it the correct way. Could you perhaps rephrase the beginning of your sentence to be more explicit...  Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: This should be marked as the accepted answer. Highly detailed and the Platform Abstraction Layer is used internally in Aurelia dependencies and functionality because it handles feature detection and fallbacks for most things in the DOM. If you are working with just ``document.getElementById`` or querying things, the PAL dependency might be overkill, but for anything relating to eventing and modifying the DOM using evolving standards and other features like Shadow DOM, definitely using the Platform Abstraction Layer.